# spring-data-solr new release with solrj 5.x support

Tags: solrj, spring-data-solr

Does anyone know what is the release date of spring-data-solr with solrj 5.x support? Also in which version of spring-data-solr it will be available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be available in spring-data-solr 2.0 but release date is not yet disclosed.

Comment: Solr has gotten to version 5.4 and closing fast to 1 year since 5.0 was released and SD4Solr is not out yet. I'm really dissapointed

Comment: Yes, its really disappointing to see such a slow pace in releasing spring-data-solr 2.0. I am also waiting for the release.

Comment: see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Hopper for release dates